# Hamiltonian path- Lower bound of optimal solution

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, hamiltonian-path

I am trying to find an algorithm with polynomial run time that calculates the lower bound of the optimal solution on the Hamiltonian Path problem( a lower bound to the sum weight of the hamiltonian path).

My first thought was to place the edges in ascending order and pick one edge at a time.
But this is like kruskal.
Any ideas might be helpful

Comment: what do you mean by the lower bound in this context?

Comment: Sorry i forget it. Lower bound means the lower bound of the sum weight of the hamiltonian path

Comment: forgot* My english is bad (:)

Comment: Maybe  kruskal and prim  algorithms has a polynomial run time? I am confused.

Comment: Could you be more precise, please? What do you mean by the sum weight of the hamiltonian path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because a Hamiltonian path is a spanning tree, computing a minimum spanning tree (MST) provides a lower bound on every Hamiltonian path.  And you can compute a MST in polynomial time.  Here, you are enforcing connectivity but relaxing the degree-2 constraints.

Another polynomially computable lower bound arises from using a dummy node to convert to Hamiltonian tour and then solving an assignment problem to find a minimum-weight union of cycles.  Here, you are enforcing the degree-2 constraints but relaxing connectivity.